# How to do Tooling API Query filtering name

Tags: soql, tooling-api

```
/services/data/v45.0/tooling/query?q=select+id,FullName+from+globalvalueset+limit+1
```

I'm able to fetch the one of the records.

```
/services/data/v45.0/tooling/query?q=select+id,FullName+from+globalvalueset+Where+FullName='Structure'+limit+1
```

Error message:

> FullName from globalvalueset Where FullName='Structure' limit 1 ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:46 field 'FullName' can not be filtered in a query call

I only have name to fetch the ID. How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for [`GlobalValueSet`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_globalvalueset.htm), it seems the field you were actually looking for may be **`MasterLabel`**.